# добрый день. начинаю изучать VUE3, не могу решить проблему с отображением компонентов

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

есть компоненты TheHeader, HomePage. внутри HomePage находятся TasksPage, PackagesPage и некоторые другие. в хедере есть раскрывающееся меню, и пир нажатии на пункт меню должны скрываться/отображаться соответствующие данные компонентов.
вот пример отображения компонентов в HomePage:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <router-view>
      <TasksPage v-if="activePage === 'tasks'" class="menu-content"/>
    </router-view>
    <router-view>
      <PackagesPage :show-packages="showPackages" class="menu-content" v-show="activePage === 'packages'"/>
    </router-view>
    <BillsPage class="menu-content"/>
    <ProjectsPage class="menu-content" />
    <FAQPage class="menu-content" />
    <LicensesPage class="menu-content" />
  </div>
</template>
```

я не понимаю как в Хедер передать динамическое отображение контента исходя из того, на какой пункт нажали. подскажите пожалуйста!
вот пример кода Хедера

```
          <div class="offcanvas-body">
            <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end">
              <li class="nav-item w-100 m-2" @click="activePage = 'tasks'">
                <router-link to="/tasks" class="nav-elem col bg-secondary text-light rounded p-3">
                  Задачи
              </router-link>
                </li>
              <li class="nav-item w-100 m-2" @click="activePage = 'packages'">
                <router-link to="/packages" class="nav-elem col bg-secondary text-light rounded p-3">
                  Пакеты ТП
                </router-link>
              </li>
```